# Query menu_order custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, php, menus

I added `'supports' => 'page-attributes'` to my custom post type, and now i have the meta box for page ordering.

When i use the argument `'sort_column' => 'menu_order'` with `get_pages()` on my custom post type, everything orders properly.

So why do the custom pages not order properly when i query the posts using `query_posts(array('orderby' => 'menu_order'))`

And what can i do to get them to order by the menu order?

Here is the query im using incase anyone wants to see it.

```
<?php 
    $current_term = ($wp_query->query_vars['section'] <> '') ? $wp_query->query_vars['section'] : $menu_arr[0]; 
    query_posts(array(  'post_type' => 'module', 
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'tax_query' => array(array( 'taxonomy' => 'section', 
                                    'field' => 'slug', 
                                    'terms' => $current_term )),
        'post_parent' => 0 ));
?>
```

Comment: Elaborate on _not order properly_? How are they sorted in that case?

Comment: Its as if the query can not find 'menu_order' from the custom posts. The query currently is ignoring the argument.

Comment: Is it query for multiple post types? If you query in that way for native pages is menu_order applied?

Comment: It is for a single post type. And all the arguments are proper. I'll update the code question with my code for the query.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've just had to do the same thing as you, here is what I did to get this working:

`'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes')`

Register the post type with supports of page attributes. This adds the menu order meta box to the edit screen. From there you can place the order.

Then run my custom query:

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_type' => 'staff'
);
$staff = get_posts($args);
```

set `orderby` to menu_order and `order` to ASC. Remember if you do not set a value in menu order it sets it to 0. So any posts without an order set will appear first.

Comment: Thanks, i ended up getting this to work a while back. But i appreciate it! ;)

Comment: In case anyone else is scratching their heads over this, it's the presence of the 'order' argument that is required to make it work. I had set `'order_by' => 'menu_order'` and it didn't work until I also added `'order' => 'ASC'`

Comment: I was having trouble with `get_posts` with Wordpress 3.4.1.  Didn't start working until I shifted to using `query_posts`

Comment: Can confirm - March 2018, still fails without the `'order' => 'ASC'` part as well as the `orderby` clause. Weird, but, there ya go.

Answer (score 2):

in my functions.php i used this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_Videos' );
function create_Videos() {
    register_post_type('videos', array(
        'label' => __('Videos'),
        'singular_label' => __('Video'),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'article',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => false,
        'query_var' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'page-attributes')
    ));
}
```

and in my theme that:

```
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_type' => 'videos'
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

This is what worked for me
Bye

Answer (score 0):

`sort_column=menu_order` only sorts pages based on their order in writing not the order you set in `view > menus` (translated), if you want that you can do like this:

```
$children = get_pages('child_of='. $topID); 

// 'sort_column=menu_order' <-- only sorts by post order in writing mode (page > edit) not the menu order set in view > menus
// wp_nav_menu has what we need, let's sort it the same way.
$options = array(
    'container' =>  '',
    'echo'      =>  false,
);                      
$nav = wp_nav_menu($options);       
$nav = strip_tags($nav);        
$nav = str_replace("\r", '', $nav);
$nav = explode("\n", $nav);
//print_r($nav);
$newChildren = array();
foreach ($nav as $item) {
    $item = trim($item);
    $run = true;
    for ($c = 0; $c < count($children) && run; $c++) {              
        $child = $children[$c];
        if (strcmp($child->post_title, $item) == 0 && !in_array($child, $newChildren)) {
            $newChildren[] = $child;                    
            $run = false;
        }
    }

    // Adding the children the nav_menu is lacking, not sure why not all sub-children 
    //  are added to the first child here..(works but don't know why :/)
    if ($run == true) {
        for ($c = 0; $c < count($children) && run; $c++) {              
            $child = $children[$c];     
            if (!in_array($child, $newChildren)) {
                $newChildren[] = $child;
            }
        }           
    }
}
$children = $newChildren;
```